# Age In Years Of Youngest Employee

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `employees` and I I need to get the age of the youngest employee in years.

For example if I look at the table the youngest employee is "57 years old"

The columns:

```
EmployeeID, Lastname, Title, Birthdate, Hiredate, City, Country
```

The code I was trying was this:

```
SELECT MAX(birthdate)
FROM employees;
```

With that I can get the date of birth of the youngest employee, but now I need to somehow compare it with the current date that would be using "sysdate" and then change it to numbers so that it shows that he is 57 years old, but I have not succeeded

Comment: I think you meant to use `MIN` function to find the youngest employee...

Comment: At first I thought like you, but no.
In this case, **"MAX"** would be used, since the highest birthday is the youngest person.

I will give you an example, if I put **"MAX"** I get the date 1966, but if I put **"MIN"** I get the date 1930.
If you compare it with the current date using the **"MAX"** is the youngest and **"MIN"** the oldest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, MAX(birthdate))/12) AS age
FROM   employees;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( id, birthdate ) AS
-- First employee will be 20 tomorrow
SELECT 1, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -20*12) + INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- Second employee is 25 today
SELECT 2, ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -25*12) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| AGE |
| --- |
| 19 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KevG3dvF)

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract your MAX(birthdate) from SYSDATE - the result is number of days so you should convert days to years.

```
WITH 
    tbl AS 
        (
            select 
                to_date('09-09-1965', 'dd-mm-yyyy') birthdate,
                SYSDATE my_sysdate
            from   dual
        )
SELECT FLOOR((my_sysdate - MAX(birthdate))/ 365) "YEARS_OLD" From tbl

  YEARS_OLD
-----------
         57
```

Comment: Thank you very much, they worked for me.
I would like to ask you what exactly is "SELECT FLOOR" for?

Comment: Floor function returns integer part of decimal number. Like 5.134 is 5.and 5.999 is also 5.the Ceil function would return 6 in both cases.

Comment: This can give the wrong answer (as 1-in-4 years there are not 365 days in a year). [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ndnnZP3O)

Comment: The question was asking for an answer in years - not months or days. Yes it could give the wrong answer in any precision less than  a year, but if the precision was set up to days then someone could say that it could miss the hours or minutes or.... The question is explicite - in years.

Comment: See the previous fiddle or [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N7u75vE_). Because you are not accurately measuring years, you have a gradually expanding window between the actual birthday and the date which your query incorrectly calculates a new year to start. For a 57 year-old employee, your calculation is out by 14 days so you have a 14 day window where it is wrong by an entire year. If you take an extreme example and calculate the age of someone 6000 years old then your calculation would report them as 6004 years old (i.e. the calculation is gradually worse the larger the gap between dates).

Comment: @MT0 If someone ask me about my age 14 days before or 14 days after my 61st birthday, my answer will be 61 - knowingly accepting the risk that I could end up in hell as an apsolute layer. In all the rest you are right, though I didn't hear about 6000 years old employee.

Comment: If the government says, "you can have your pension if you are 61" then you do not say "Its okay, I'll be 61 in a few weeks so I think I'm eligible for it now." You are either 61 or you are not 61; and the change from 60 to 61 occurs on your birthday. The example of 6000 years is just to show you how wrong your code goes when you let the errors propagate over many years.

Comment: @MT0 It was about youngest employee info for company (probably) - not for government and retirement - so, claiming that someone is 19 years old a day before his 20th birthday (how ever right it is and, once more, you are right - it is) is just a big fat lay to the company the info is for. Anyway, this (overcommenting) doesn't make sense at all and I could just quote the last Littlefoot's coment : "...agree that we don't agree and it's ok"

Answer (score -1):

If you don't care much about months and days, a simple option is to extract **year** from sysdate and youngest birthdate and subtract them:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with employees (employeeid, lastname, birthdate) as
  2    (select 1, 'Little', date '2015-08-25' from dual union all  --> youngest
  3     select 2, 'Foot'  , date '2000-11-13' from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select extract(year from sysdate) - extract(year from max(birthdate)) as age
  6  from employees;

       AGE
----------
         8

SQL>
```

Comment: @Shiro This gives the wrong answer for anyone who has not had their birthday yet this year [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kjm3draQ)

Comment: @MT0, how many employees are *babies*?

Comment: Let us assume that the youngest employee was born 2000-12-31 and today is 2023-01-01. They had their 22nd birthday yesterday and if we do 2023-2000 that gives us 23 so for that employee, this answer would be wrong for 364 days of the year. I have no idea why you think babies are relevant because this answer will be wrong and add an extra year to the expected result for every employee who has not had their birthday yet in the current year.

Comment: @MT0, please, don't *assume*. My first sentence says: "If you don't care much about months and days ...". I explicitly explained conditions that return result based on query I posted. Everything you said is correct, but doesn't apply to what I wrote.

Comment: It does apply because the OP asked for age. If a person is 22 years and 1 day old then the OP wants to know that they are 22 years old. Your answer is just as likely to say that they are 23 years old as it is to say that they are 22 years old because it will return the wrong amount of years for all employees that have not had their birthday yet in the current year.

Comment: Apparently, we agree that we don't agree, which is quite OK.